# Вывод в jTextArea

Tags: java

Подскажите, как можно выводить в jTextArea2 много строк

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    jTextArea2.setText(new String( new char[] {a[i]}));
}
```

Comment: в цикле строку s += new String(new char...); собрать, а потом её в textArea или в чём-то другом вопрос?..

Comment: может бы ты сел и прочитал про работу строг в яве??

Comment: а по другому можно как то? что бы добавлять непосредственно в jTextArea2 так как в дальнейшем коде придется еще добавлять на вывод в это же окно

Comment: После того, как увидел ответ, дошёл смысл вопроса) сори)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    String text = ....
    jTextArea2.append(text);
}
```

Comment: Да работает. Спасибо!